# PowerShell Get-Date into Switch Statement

Tags: date, powershell, switch-statement

I'm trying to create a `SWITCH` statement in PowerShell to run different code blocks based on `DayOfWeek` from `Get-Date` and I thought I had it working until I tested by setting a specific date, I found the code wasn't working as expected.

In the perfect world, the script will be run on Monday.  My goal is to output three variables in these formats `2/02/2015 1:00 AM 2015-02-02 MONDAY` basically adding one day from Monday until Monday of next week.

The problem comes from my trying to anticipate the script being run on another day besides Monday.  So I'm wanting to use `(Get-Date).AddDays($i)` to output the correct dates but when I tried setting a date in the future with Get-Date, the returned dates were incorrect.

When I started testing using `$var = (get-date -Year 2015 -Month 02 -Day 04).DayOfWeek` to set a specific Date, the switch statement didn't output the correct dates.

**In summary, PowerShell Switch statement to Get-Date and output 7 dates in a range.  Tues,Wed,Thur,Fri,Sat,Sun,Mon(next week)**

Here's the switch statement:

```psh
#$var = (get-date).DayOfWeek
$var = [DayOfWeek]::Sunday
#$var = (get-date -Year 2015 -Month 02 -Day 04).DayOfWeek
Switch ($var){
([DayOfWeek] 'Monday'){
for ($i = 1; $i -le 7; $i++){
 $d = ((Get-Date).AddDays($i))
 $d2 = ($d.ToString("M/dd/yyyy") + " 1:00 AM")
 $d3 = ($d.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"))
 $d4 = (($d).DayOfWeek).ToString().ToUpper()
"$d2 $d3 $d4"}#End For
}#End Monday
([DayOfWeek] 'Tuesday'){
$i= 5,-1,0,1,2,3,4
foreach ($day in $i){
 $d = ((Get-Date).AddDays($day))
 $d2 = ($d.ToString("M/dd/yyyy") + " 1:00 AM")
 $d3 = ($d.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"))
 $d4 = (($d).DayOfWeek).ToString().ToUpper()
"$d2 $d3 $d4"}#End For
}#End Tuesday
([DayOfWeek] 'Wednesday'){
$i= 5,-1,0,1,2,3,4
foreach ($day in $i){
 $d = ((Get-Date).AddDays($day))
 $d2 = ($d.ToString("M/dd/yyyy") + " 1:00 AM")
 $d3 = ($d.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"))
 $d4 = (($d).DayOfWeek).ToString().ToUpper()
"$d2 $d3 $d4"}#End For
}#End Wednesday
([DayOfWeek] 'Thursday'){
$i= 4,-1,0,1,2,3,4
foreach ($day in $i){
 $d = ((Get-Date).AddDays($day))
 $d2 = ($d.ToString("M/dd/yyyy") + " 1:00 AM")
 $d3 = ($d.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"))
 $d4 = (($d).DayOfWeek).ToString().ToUpper()
"$d2 $d3 $d4"}#End For
}#End Thursday
([DayOfWeek] 'Friday'){
$i= 5,-1,0,1,2,3,4
foreach ($day in $i){
 $d = ((Get-Date).AddDays($day))
 $d2 = ($d.ToString("M/dd/yyyy") + " 1:00 AM")
 $d3 = ($d.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"))
 $d4 = (($d).DayOfWeek).ToString().ToUpper()
"$d2 $d3 $d4"}#End For
}#End Friday
([DayOfWeek] 'Saturday'){
$i= 5,-1,0,1,2,3,4
foreach ($day in $i){
 $d = ((Get-Date).AddDays($day))
 $d2 = ($d.ToString("M/dd/yyyy") + " 1:00 AM")
 $d3 = ($d.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"))
 $d4 = (($d).DayOfWeek).ToString().ToUpper()
"$d2 $d3 $d4"}#End For
}#End Saturday
([DayOfWeek] 'Sunday'){
$i= 1,-1,0,1,2,3,4
foreach ($day in $i){
 $d = ((Get-Date).AddDays($day))
 $d2 = ($d.ToString("M/dd/yyyy") + " 1:00 AM")
 $d3 = ($d.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"))
 $d4 = (($d).DayOfWeek).ToString().ToUpper()
"$d2 $d3 $d4"}#End For
}#End Sunday
}#End Switch
```

Then you can make every instance of `Get-Date` in the script return whatever arbitrary date you want by setting it in the `Get-Date` proxy function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may be helpful. No switch, just math. You can change the formatting string to whatever you like. Just change "yyyy-MM-dd dddd HH:mm tt". See [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for details on getting the output exactly as you want it.

```
function get-nextweek ([System.DateTime]$p1)
{
    #Set the time to 01:00
    $p1 = [DateTime]($p1.Date + "01:00")
    # + 1 week + 2 days (Tuesday) - Current day of week (0 based) % 7 + 0..6
    0..6 | %{
             #get number of days till Monday
             $d = (8-$p1.DayOfWeek)%7+$_
             #Add 7 if today is Monday to get next week
             if($d -eq 0){$d=7}
             #Output the days as a custom string
             $out = $p1.AddDays($d)
             "$($out.ToString('MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm tt yyyy-MM-dd')) $($out.DayOfWeek.ToString().ToUpper())"
    }
}
```

Output:

```
C:\ > get-nextweek '01-29-2015'
02/02/2015 01:00 AM 2015-02-02 MONDAY
02/03/2015 01:00 AM 2015-02-03 TUESDAY
02/04/2015 01:00 AM 2015-02-04 WEDNESDAY
02/05/2015 01:00 AM 2015-02-05 THURSDAY
02/06/2015 01:00 AM 2015-02-06 FRIDAY
02/07/2015 01:00 AM 2015-02-07 SATURDAY
02/08/2015 01:00 AM 2015-02-08 SUNDAY
```

Comment: I'd love to condense the script that much!  I have to apologize because I'm terrible at trying to explain these things.  How about this, Monday of current week we add 7,6,5,4,3,2,1 days giving Monday of next week followed by Tues,Wed,Thur,Fri,Sat,Sun of the current week.  If run on Tuesday, its still Monday next week then add 0,1,2,3,4,5,6 days.  My problem is working out the `Get-Date` math to account for that.  I'm even tempted to make the user enter the date as a `param` then do math on that.

Comment: If I run the script today, 29-Jan-2015, I should get as Output: 2/02/2015 1:00 AM 2015-02-02 MONDAY
1/27/2015 1:00 AM 2015-01-27 TUESDAY
1/28/2015 1:00 AM 2015-01-28 WEDNESDAY
1/29/2015 1:00 AM 2015-01-29 THURSDAY
1/30/2015 1:00 AM 2015-01-30 FRIDAY
1/31/2015 1:00 AM 2015-01-31 SATURDAY
2/01/2015 1:00 AM 2015-02-01 SUNDAY

Comment: That's very close however I need the three variables with the three date formats.  I'm trying `$d4 = ($p1.DayOfWeek).ToString().ToUpper()` but all I get in return is `MONDAY` and `$d4 = ($p1).DayOfWeek.ToString().ToUpper()` also doesn't work.

Comment: I have updated the format string. You can adjust it to whatever you need.

Comment: How would this handle be run on Tuesday or Wednesday?  That was my sole reason for walking down this path.
Thanks, I managed to work this out by doing:  `             $d2 = ($p1.AddDays($d).ToString("M/dd/yyyy")) + " 1:00 AM"
             $d3 = ($p1.AddDays($d).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd"))
             $d4 = ($p1.AddDays($d).DayOfWeek.ToString().ToUpper())`

Comment: If run on Tuesday or Wednesday it outputs the next week starting from Monday.

Comment: I see, here's where the math got weird for me.  If run on Tuesday, I'd need to get Next monday and tues-sun of the current week.  Offset of course the later the script is run in the week.  As such I'm going to try working out a check before the script is run preventing it from running on other days, keep things simple! -Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Edit:
After look at your comments and poking at it a bit, I was able to condense it down to this:

```
$LastMonday = 
(Get-Date).adddays(-(1..7)[[int](Get-Date).DayOfWeek -2])

 ,7+(1..6)| foreach {
   $d = ($LastMonday.AddDays($_))
   $d2 = ($d.ToString("M/dd/yyyy") + " 1:00 AM")
   $d3 = ($d.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"))
   $d4 = (($d).DayOfWeek).ToString().ToUpper()
   "$d2 $d3 $d4"}

2/02/2015 1:00 AM 2015-02-02 MONDAY
1/27/2015 1:00 AM 2015-01-27 TUESDAY
1/28/2015 1:00 AM 2015-01-28 WEDNESDAY
1/29/2015 1:00 AM 2015-01-29 THURSDAY
1/30/2015 1:00 AM 2015-01-30 FRIDAY
1/31/2015 1:00 AM 2015-01-31 SATURDAY
2/01/2015 1:00 AM 2015-02-01 SUNDAY
```

I think the problem may be with your testing methodology.

I test scripts that do date-time math from Get-Date like this:

```
function get-date {[datetime]'02/04/2015'}

$var = (get-date).DayOfWeek
#$var = [DayOfWeek]::Sunday
#$var = (get-date -Year 2015 -Month 02 -Day 04).DayOfWeek
Switch ($var){
([DayOfWeek] 'Monday'){
for ($i = 1; $i -le 7; $i++){
 $d = ((Get-Date).AddDays($i))
 $d2 = ($d.ToString("M/dd/yyyy") + " 1:00 AM")
 $d3 = ($d.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"))
 $d4 = (($d).DayOfWeek).ToString().ToUpper()
"$d2 $d3 $d4"}#End For
}#End Monday
([DayOfWeek] 'Tuesday'){
$i= 5,-1,0,1,2,3,4
foreach ($day in $i){
 $d = ((Get-Date).AddDays($day))
 $d2 = ($d.ToString("M/dd/yyyy") + " 1:00 AM")
 $d3 = ($d.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"))
 $d4 = (($d).DayOfWeek).ToString().ToUpper()
"$d2 $d3 $d4"}#End For
}#End Tuesday
([DayOfWeek] 'Wednesday'){
$i= 5,-1,0,1,2,3,4
foreach ($day in $i){
 $d = ((Get-Date).AddDays($day))
 $d2 = ($d.ToString("M/dd/yyyy") + " 1:00 AM")
 $d3 = ($d.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"))
 $d4 = (($d).DayOfWeek).ToString().ToUpper()
"$d2 $d3 $d4"}#End For
}#End Wednesday
([DayOfWeek] 'Thursday'){
$i= 4,-1,0,1,2,3,4
foreach ($day in $i){
 $d = ((Get-Date).AddDays($day))
 $d2 = ($d.ToString("M/dd/yyyy") + " 1:00 AM")
 $d3 = ($d.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"))
 $d4 = (($d).DayOfWeek).ToString().ToUpper()
"$d2 $d3 $d4"}#End For
}#End Thursday
([DayOfWeek] 'Friday'){
$i= 5,-1,0,1,2,3,4
foreach ($day in $i){
 $d = ((Get-Date).AddDays($day))
 $d2 = ($d.ToString("M/dd/yyyy") + " 1:00 AM")
 $d3 = ($d.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"))
 $d4 = (($d).DayOfWeek).ToString().ToUpper()
"$d2 $d3 $d4"}#End For
}#End Friday
([DayOfWeek] 'Saturday'){
$i= 5,-1,0,1,2,3,4
foreach ($day in $i){
 $d = ((Get-Date).AddDays($day))
 $d2 = ($d.ToString("M/dd/yyyy") + " 1:00 AM")
 $d3 = ($d.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"))
 $d4 = (($d).DayOfWeek).ToString().ToUpper()
"$d2 $d3 $d4"}#End For
}#End Saturday
([DayOfWeek] 'Sunday'){
$i= 1,-1,0,1,2,3,4
foreach ($day in $i){
 $d = ((Get-Date).AddDays($day))
 $d2 = ($d.ToString("M/dd/yyyy") + " 1:00 AM")
 $d3 = ($d.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"))
 $d4 = (($d).DayOfWeek).ToString().ToUpper()
"$d2 $d3 $d4"}#End For
}#End Sunday
}#End Switch
```

Comment: I'd never have thought of doing that @mjolinor and all the research I've done into this never even hinted at that.  The tests now look good, how would I wrap this up so when the script's run it'll work out the DayOfWeek then output the correct range of dates.


2/23/2015 1:00 AM 2015-02-23 MONDAY
2/17/2015 1:00 AM 2015-02-17 TUESDAY
2/18/2015 1:00 AM 2015-02-18 WEDNESDAY
2/19/2015 1:00 AM 2015-02-19 THURSDAY
2/20/2015 1:00 AM 2015-02-20 FRIDAY
2/21/2015 1:00 AM 2015-02-21 SATURDAY
2/22/2015 1:00 AM 2015-02-22 SUNDAY

Comment: Is there anything obviously wrong in doing `$var = [DateTime]::Now.DayOfWeek` because that is `System.Enum` and maybe would play nice with my Frankenstein script?

Comment: This is just a suggestion for testing methodology.  It was late, and I didn't really dissect the script.  When I write scripts that rely on datetime math I avoid using static datetime methods like [datetime]::Now in favor of Get-Date because it cirumvents being able to test arbitrary dates like this, using a proxy function for Get-Date .

Comment: After seeing the comments, I added a proposed solution to simplify the script.